# Javascript execution breaks with a TypeError message "Cannot read property 'refcount' of undefined" only if a class method is called inside a loop

Tags: javascript, c++, emscripten, webassembly

I've built a template stack class in C++:

**stack.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <emscripten/bind.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace emscripten;

template<class T>
class Stack {
    private:
    int size = 0;
    val *arr;

    public:
    Stack() {
        this->arr = new val(0);
    }

    void Push(val element) {
        val *temp = this->arr;
        this->arr = new val(this->size + 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < this->size; i++) {
            this->arr[i] = temp[i];
        }
        this->arr[this->size] = element;
        this->size++;
    }

    val Pop() {
        if (this->size == 0) {
            throw new underflow_error("Underflow eror.\nNothing to pop.");
        }
        else {
            val *temp = this->arr;
            val element = this->arr[this->size - 1];
            this->size--;
            this->arr = new val(this->size);
            for (int i = 0; i < this->size; i++) {
                this->arr[i] = temp[i];
            }
            return element;
        }
    }

    val Top() {
        if (this->size == 0) {
            throw new underflow_error("Underflow eror.\nThe stack is empty.");
        }
        else {
            return this->arr[this->size - 1];
        }
    }

    void Flush() {
        while (this->size != 0) {
            this->Pop();
        }
    }

    int Size() {
        return this->size;
    }
};

    EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(Stack) {
    class_<Stack<val>>("Stack")
    .constructor<>()
    .function("Push", &Stack<val>::Push)
    .function("Pop", &Stack<val>::Pop)
    .function("Top", &Stack<val>::Top)
    .function("Flush", &Stack<val>::Flush)
    .function("Size", &Stack<val>::Size);
}

int main() {
    cout << "Loaded" << endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

In the command line interface , i've compiled this file into a WASM module using the following command:

`emcc -O0 --bind -o stack.js stack.cpp -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_main']"`

This generates two files , `stack.js` and `stack.wasm`.
Inside the page , i'am loading the WASM module using the following code:

**stack.js:**

```
<script src="stack.js"></script>
<script>
    window.addEventListener("load", () => {
        Module["onRuntimeInitialized"] = () => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                let s = new Module.Stack();
                for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                    s.Push(8);
                }
            }, 4000);
        };
    });
</script>
```

The problem happens at the call of the `Push()` method inside the loop.
The execution breaks with the following error message in the browser's console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'refcount' of undefined
    at __emval_decref (stack.js:6340)
    at wasm-function[111]:62
    at wasm-function[72]:248
    at wasm-function[112]:168
    at wasm-function[1062]:17
    at dynCall_viii_344 (eval at makeDynCaller (stack.js:5913), <anonymous>:4:12)
    at Stack$Push [as Push] (eval at new_ (stack.js:6172), <anonymous>:9:1)
    at setTimeout (test.html:19)
```

If i ever called any of the methods outside the loop , everything works fine.

I'm using **emscripten 1.38.11** with **clang 6.0.1**

I'm not sure where does the problem exactly occurs.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: why is a javascript runtime error tagged with C++?

Comment: @xaxxon Because this technology is related to C++ , the problem here isn't all about JavaScript